# PySpark Map Data from one Dataframe to Another Empty Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

Hi I am looking to build a solution, in which there are two dataframes in pyspark. One dataframe is having n columns and another dataframe having m columns with different column names. There is not even a single column match in both dataframes.

```
example A DataFrame like

| A | B | C | D | E | F|
+------+--------+--------
| 85| 2|9494| 45| 56| 45|
| 90| 9|992 |667|  7| 77|

Another B Dataframe which is empty dataframe

| H | K | L | M | N | O|
+------+--------+--------

I want A dataframe values to be mapped in B dataframe in pyspark

| H | K | L | M | N | O|
+------+--------+--------
| 85| 2|9494| 45| 56| 45|
| 90| 9|992 |667|  7| 77|
```

Comment: Can Anyone has resolved this type of situation earlier ? Please help

Comment: how does Col A in dataframe A related to Col H in dataframe B ?

Comment: @Umar.H I am trying pass the values in Column A to Colum H in  another dataframe, I am looking for a way to build this solution. and Dataframe B is an empty dataframe.

Comment: so you're looking to rename the columns in dataframe A to match dataframe B?

Comment: @Umar.H No . As my dataframe B has more columns than my dataframe A . eg A has 4 columns and B has 7 columns. Now I want my A dataframes  which has value in its column to be mapped in columns in my Dataframe B where I want to map. For more clearance A has column name firstname and Dataframe B has column name only name. I want firstname column values in my Dataframe B Column name.